# How to get console.log line numbers shown in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js

Got an old application, that prints out quite a lot of messages using `console.log`, but I just can not find in which files and lines `console.log` is called.

Is there a way to hook into the app and show file name and line numbers?

Comment: if you want to find where is your console.log, you have to check and search in every file
Using console.log() to `log` stuff is a bad thing, you should use a proper logger function (do you own or get a npm package). Console.log() should just be used in dev to display a variable value.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For a temporary hack to find the log statements that you want to get rid of, it's not too difficult to override `console.log` yourself.

```js
var log = console.log;
console.log = function() {
    log.apply(console, arguments);
    // Print the stack trace
    console.trace();
};


// Somewhere else...
function foo(){
    console.log('Foobar');
}
foo();
```

That will print something like

```
Foobar
Trace
at Console.console.log (index.js:4:13)
at foo (index.js:10:13)
at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:12:1)
...
```

A lot of noise in there but the second line in the call stack, `at foo (index.js:10:13)`, should point you to the right place.

Comment: Another option is to use `console.trace('Foobar');` directly, it would be one line cleaner and you save one function

Comment: This leads to infinite call recursion if modified to track `console.error()`, see my answer for a solution that tracks *all* logs.

Answer (score 32):

Having full stack trace for each call is a bit noisy. I've just improved the @noppa's solution to print only the initiator:

```
['log', 'warn', 'error'].forEach((methodName) => {
  const originalMethod = console[methodName];
  console[methodName] = (...args) => {
    let initiator = 'unknown place';
    try {
      throw new Error();
    } catch (e) {
      if (typeof e.stack === 'string') {
        let isFirst = true;
        for (const line of e.stack.split('\n')) {
          const matches = line.match(/^\s+at\s+(.*)/);
          if (matches) {
            if (!isFirst) { // first line - current function
                            // second line - caller (what we are looking for)
              initiator = matches[1];
              break;
            }
            isFirst = false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    originalMethod.apply(console, [...args, '\n', `  at ${initiator}`]);
  };
});
```

It also patches other methods (useful for Nodejs, since `warn` and `error` don't come with a stack trace as in Chrome).

So your console would look something like:

```
Loading settings.json
   at fs.readdirSync.filter.forEach (.../settings.js:21:13)
Server is running on http://localhost:3000 or http://127.0.0.1:3000
   at Server.app.listen (.../index.js:67:11)
```

Comment: btw, using https://github.com/marak/colors.js/ and making this change: "at ${initiator}` .green]" really gives your line a nice distinction of color for readability

Comment: No need to `try/catch`! The `e` that you used in `catch` block, is the same `new Error()` that you raised in `try` block. Just store in it in a variable and use it (`const e = new Error()`).

Answer (score 24):

All solutions to this question so far rely on splitting and matching the stack trace as a string, which will break in (the unlikely) case the format of that string is changed in the future. Inspired by [this gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/mikesmullin/008721d4753d3e0d9a95cda617874736) and the other answers here, I want to provide my own solution:

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');

['debug', 'log', 'warn', 'error'].forEach((methodName) => {
    const originalLoggingMethod = console[methodName];
    console[methodName] = (firstArgument, ...otherArguments) => {
        const originalPrepareStackTrace = Error.prepareStackTrace;
        Error.prepareStackTrace = (_, stack) => stack;
        const callee = new Error().stack[1];
        Error.prepareStackTrace = originalPrepareStackTrace;
        const relativeFileName = path.relative(process.cwd(), callee.getFileName());
        const prefix = `${relativeFileName}:${callee.getLineNumber()}:`;
        if (typeof firstArgument === 'string') {
            originalLoggingMethod(prefix + ' ' + firstArgument, ...otherArguments);
        } else {
            originalLoggingMethod(prefix, firstArgument, ...otherArguments);
        }
    };
});

// Tests:
console.log('%s %d', 'hi', 42);
console.log({ a: 'foo', b: 'bar'});
```

Unlike the other solutions, this script

- outputs no additional lines and
- handles [string substitutions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Using_string_substitutions) correctly.

You can color the `prefix` with [chalk](https://github.com/chalk/chalk) or [color.js](https://github.com/marak/colors.js/), but I didn't want to introduce dependencies for this here.

The above script uses the [V8 API to customize stack traces](https://v8.dev/docs/stack-trace-api#customizing-stack-traces). The `callee` is a `CallSite` object with the following methods in case you want to customize the `prefix`:

> - `getThis`: returns the value of `this`
> - `getTypeName`: returns the type of `this` as a string. This is the name of the function stored in the constructor field of `this`, if available, otherwise the object’s `[[Class]]` internal property.
> - `getFunction`: returns the current function
> - `getFunctionName`: returns the name of the current function, typically its `name` property. If a `name` property is not available an attempt is made to infer a name from the function’s context.
> - `getMethodName`: returns the name of the property of `this` or one of its prototypes that holds the current function
> - `getFileName`: if this function was defined in a script returns the name of the script
> - `getLineNumber`: if this function was defined in a script returns the current line number
> - `getColumnNumber`: if this function was defined in a script returns the current column number
> - `getEvalOrigin`: if this function was created using a call to `eval` returns a string representing the location where `eval` was called
> - `isToplevel`: is this a top-level invocation, that is, is this the global object?
> - `isEval`: does this call take place in code defined by a call to `eval`?
> - `isNative`: is this call in native V8 code?
> - `isConstructor`: is this a constructor call?
> - `isAsync`: is this an async call (i.e. `await` or `Promise.all()`)?
> - `isPromiseAll`: is this an async call to `Promise.all()`?
> - `getPromiseIndex`: returns the index of the promise element that was followed in `Promise.all()` for async stack traces, or `null` if the `CallSite` is not a `Promise.all()` call.

This answer is a cross-post of [an answer I just gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60305639/12917821) to a similar question as more people might find this page.

Answer (score 8):

I found [Dmitry Druganov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47296370/5503625) really nice, but I tried it on Windows 10 (with Node 8.9.4) and it didn't work well. It was printing the full path, something like:

```
Loading settings.json
   at fs.readdirSync.filter.forEach (D:\Users\Piyin\Projects\test\settings.js:21:13)
Server is running on http://localhost:3000 or http://127.0.0.1:3000
   at Server.app.listen (D:\Users\Piyin\Projects\test\index.js:67:11)
```

So I took said answer and made these improvements (from my point of view):

- Assume the important line of the stack trace is the third one (the first one is the word `Error` and the second one is where you place this script)
- Remove the current script folder path (given by [__dirname](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname), which in my case is `D:\Users\Piyin\Projects\test`). *Note: For this to work well, the script should be on the project's main Javascript*
- Remove the starting `at`
- Place the file information before the actual log
- Format the information as `Class.method at path/to/file:line:column`

Here it is:

```
['log','warn','error'].forEach((methodName) => {
  const originalMethod = console[methodName];
  console[methodName] = (...args) => {
    try {
      throw new Error();
    } catch (error) {
      originalMethod.apply(
        console,
        [
          (
            error
            .stack // Grabs the stack trace
            .split('\n')[2] // Grabs third line
            .trim() // Removes spaces
            .substring(3) // Removes three first characters ("at ")
            .replace(__dirname, '') // Removes script folder path
            .replace(/\s\(./, ' at ') // Removes first parentheses and replaces it with " at "
            .replace(/\)/, '') // Removes last parentheses
          ),
          '\n',
          ...args
        ]
      );
    }
  };
});
```

And here's the new output:

```
fs.readdirSync.filter.forEach at settings.js:21:13
 Loading settings.json
Server.app.listen at index.js:67:11
 Server is running on http://localhost:3000 or http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

Here's the minified-by-hand code (240 bytes):

```
['log','warn','error'].forEach(a=>{let b=console[a];console[a]=(...c)=>{try{throw new Error}catch(d){b.apply(console,[d.stack.split('\n')[2].trim().substring(3).replace(__dirname,'').replace(/\s\(./,' at ').replace(/\)/,''),'\n',...c])}}});
```

Comment: This will work, but throwing an error and generating a stack trace for every log entry you make will crush performance.  You should limit this functionality to only debug, trace, or verbose logging levels

Comment: In my experience, which isn't really that much, log should only be used for debugging, not for going live. So it shouldn't be a problem there, and it can be better for the developer to know exactly where each call is made. Anyway, for going live, the line can actually depend on some environment configuration so it is skipped completely

Comment: There's no need to actually throw the Error instance in order to get access to the stack. I made an edit showing the code without the throw.

Comment: Where did you make the edit? I can't see it so I can't approve it. Anyway, is it really necessary? Is it faster? Being that it's only for debug purposes I've had no problems with this approach so far

Answer (score 3):

Slightly modified version of noppa's answer, this version will output something like:

```
/file/in-which/console/is/called.js:75:23
 The stuff you want to log.
```

This is clean and convenient (especially for use in VSCode - which will turn the file path into a link).

```js
const { log } = console;
function proxiedLog(...args) {
  const line = (((new Error('log'))
    .stack.split('\n')[2] || '…')
    .match(/\(([^)]+)\)/) || [, 'not found'])[1];
  log.call(console, `${line}\n`, ...args);
}
console.info = proxiedLog;
console.log = proxiedLog;

// test
console.log('Hello!');
```

The snippet will only work well in a NodeJS environment…

Comment: Nice solution. In IntelliJ the message is transformed to a link as well.

Answer (score 0):

Appends the line number to the end of the log

```js
const stackTrace = function () {
  let obj = {}
  Error.captureStackTrace(obj, stackTrace)
  return obj.stack
}

const getLine = function (stack) {
  let matchResult = stack.match(/\(.*?\)|\s.+/g) || []
  let arr = matchResult.map((it) => {
    return it.split(' ').pop().replace(/\(|\)/g, '')
  })
  return arr[1] ?? ''
}

const log = function (...args) {
  let stack = stackTrace() || ''
  let matchResult = getLine(stack)
  let line = matchResult
  for (var i in arguments) {
    if (typeof arguments[i] == 'object') {
      // util.inspect(arguments[i], false, 2, false)
      arguments[i] = JSON.stringify(arguments[i])
    }
  }
  arguments[i] += '  ' + line
  console.log.apply(console, arguments)
}

log("test")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple & exhaustive solution if you want to temporarily find the origin of logs:

```js
{
  const logOriginal = process.stdout.write
  // @ts-ignore
  const log = (msg) => logOriginal.call(process.stdout, msg + '\n')
  ;['stdout', 'stderr'].forEach((stdName) => {
    // @ts-ignore
    var methodOriginal = process[stdName].write
    // @ts-ignore
    process[stdName].write = function (...args) {
      log('LOG:')
      // @ts-ignore
      methodOriginal.apply(process[stdName], args)
      // @ts-ignore
      log(new Error().stack.replace(/^Error/, 'LOGGED FROM:'))
    }
  })

  Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity
}
```

Answer (score -3):

const  showName = (name) => {

```
      return 

      console.log(name)
```

}

showName(“Crush”)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).