# Displaying file and line for console logs from a Node codebase

Tags: node.js, logging

I have a large Node.js codebase and I am getting console logs in my terminal and I don't know what is sending them.

Is there a way to display the file and line that these logs are coming from, similar to how it would in a stack trace?

Comment: That depends on *what*, exactly, is emitting them. Bash itself doesn't have that functionality -- it's something else you're running that's writing your logged content to the console.

Comment: ...if it's a Node logging framework, for example, then you need to look into that logging framework, not into bash. When the shell runs a program, it hands that program a direct handle on its stdout and stderr -- which is to say, bash doesn't have any way to intermediate how other programs write to the console; when a program you started writes a log message, that log message goes straight from the program to the terminal, not program->bash->terminal.

Comment: Edited the question to no longer be about bash (since bash can't possibly do what you're asking for on its own).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get console.log line numbers shown in Nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395369/how-to-get-console-log-line-numbers-shown-in-nodejs)