# NestJS Logger : show line numbers

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, nestjs

```
@Controller('v2/foobar')
export class FoobarController {

    private readonly logger = new Logger(FoobarController.name);

    constructor(readonly foobarService: FoobarService,
                readonly persistenceManager: PersistenceManager) {
    }
}
```

Given a logger that's set up according to best practice, how can I support showing the source-file's line number in NestJS?

Comment: Checkout this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395369/how-to-get-console-log-line-numbers-shown-in-nodejs - you can provide a custom logger with a solution provided from the linked question

Comment: @AustinMehmet Thank you. You can post an answer if you like? (Btw I ended up solving, but didn't share the solution! Sorry. Back working on iOS atm, so not easy for me to dig it up).