# node.js source file of a log entry?

Tags: node.js

[image]

I got log entries like this, probably the result of a `console.log` somewhere. How do I figure out which source file it's from?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to say from the log alone. You either need to look for all code that logs stuff or do some modification (likely - overwrite the logging function with slightly custom logic) and then look at the new log later on.

Comment: @VLAZ was hoping that there was a npm module that does that custom logging already?

Comment: There probably is but I think you'd also need to change all `console.log`s to `whatevermodule.log` calls. I am not sure there is a module that just overrides the default logging, although there might be. [I've written before about overwriting logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634926/how-to-disable-console-log-messages-based-on-criteria-from-specific-javascript-s/) and I think parts of this might be of use to you. I'll try to do some research for Node specifically and post an answer here, if I find anything useful.

Comment: @VLAZ found the answer here. Thanks for your help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395369/how-to-get-console-log-line-numbers-shown-in-nodejs

Comment: @VLAZ ahh this is what I wanted: https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug-trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ahh this is what I wanted: npmjs.com/package/debug-trace