# Node.js see where the console was log

Tags: node.js

For example if I do `console.log` in Chrome, it will show me where it was log like `grant.js:1`, can I get similar info in Node.js with some type of flag perhaps while starting the process?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395369/how-to-get-console-log-line-numbers-shown-in-nodejs

Comment: @ HarshaHR this prints out the trace which is a bit (actually very) ugly to read.

Comment: Also for some log printed in node_modules it doesn't print out the trace.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tracer. I never tried this, Please try this and let me know.

Comment: @AeroWang, has your problem been solved by now? Does my answer achieve what you were looking for? Regarding "for some log printed in node_modules it doesn't print out the trace": This probably depends on the order of execution. If you need help with that, please provide an example.

Comment: @KasparEtter no it's not a good solution. I modified the node itself to get console printed out thank you.

Answer (score 5):

After doing a bit of research on this, it seems to me that you really have to implement this feature yourself. As [HarshaHR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12502862/harshahr) pointed out, this question [has been answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45395369/12917821). You just need to scroll down a bit to see solutions that don't print the full stack trace.

All solutions there rely on splitting and matching the stack trace as a string, which will break if the format of that string is changed in the future. Inspired by [this gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/mikesmullin/008721d4753d3e0d9a95cda617874736) (and the answers to the similar Stack Overflow question), I want to provide my own solution:

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');

['debug', 'log', 'warn', 'error'].forEach((methodName) => {
    const originalLoggingMethod = console[methodName];
    console[methodName] = (firstArgument, ...otherArguments) => {
        const originalPrepareStackTrace = Error.prepareStackTrace;
        Error.prepareStackTrace = (_, stack) => stack;
        const callee = new Error().stack[1];
        Error.prepareStackTrace = originalPrepareStackTrace;
        const relativeFileName = path.relative(process.cwd(), callee.getFileName());
        const prefix = `${relativeFileName}:${callee.getLineNumber()}:`;
        if (typeof firstArgument === 'string') {
            originalLoggingMethod(prefix + ' ' + firstArgument, ...otherArguments);
        } else {
            originalLoggingMethod(prefix, firstArgument, ...otherArguments);
        }
    };
});

// Tests:
console.log('%s %d', 'hi', 42);
console.log({ a: 'foo', b: 'bar'});
```

Unlike the other solutions I've seen, the above script

- outputs no additional lines and
- handles [string substitutions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Using_string_substitutions) correctly.

You can color the `prefix` with [chalk](https://github.com/chalk/chalk) or [color.js](https://github.com/marak/colors.js/), but I didn't want to introduce dependencies for this here.

The above script uses the [V8 API to customize stack traces](https://v8.dev/docs/stack-trace-api#customizing-stack-traces). The `callee` is a `CallSite` object with the following methods in case you want to customize the `prefix`:

> - `getThis`: returns the value of `this`
> - `getTypeName`: returns the type of `this` as a string. This is the name of the function stored in the constructor field of `this`, if available, otherwise the object’s `[[Class]]` internal property.
> - `getFunction`: returns the current function
> - `getFunctionName`: returns the name of the current function, typically its `name` property. If a `name` property is not available an attempt is made to infer a name from the function’s context.
> - `getMethodName`: returns the name of the property of `this` or one of its prototypes that holds the current function
> - `getFileName`: if this function was defined in a script returns the name of the script
> - `getLineNumber`: if this function was defined in a script returns the current line number
> - `getColumnNumber`: if this function was defined in a script returns the current column number
> - `getEvalOrigin`: if this function was created using a call to `eval` returns a string representing the location where `eval` was called
> - `isToplevel`: is this a top-level invocation, that is, is this the global object?
> - `isEval`: does this call take place in code defined by a call to `eval`?
> - `isNative`: is this call in native V8 code?
> - `isConstructor`: is this a constructor call?
> - `isAsync`: is this an async call (i.e. `await` or `Promise.all()`)?
> - `isPromiseAll`: is this an async call to `Promise.all()`?
> - `getPromiseIndex`: returns the index of the promise element that was followed in `Promise.all()` for async stack traces, or `null` if the `CallSite` is not a `Promise.all()` call.

Comment: Your solution is great. I just want to confirm that typescript gives a different line number with the respective build. like typescript line 5 will become in build or dist folder line 2.