# Is it possible to programmatically log the line number with console.log()?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to know the line of code that the statement is on when I use console.log().  For example:

```
// line 12
console.log('hello'); // would output 13: hello
```

Is this possible to do programatically?

```
function newLog(art){
  // find line here but how
  return console.log(line, arg)
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395369/how-to-get-console-log-line-numbers-shown-in-nodejs