# How to get the line of a code at runtime in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to put a `console.log` that would inform the line where it is on. For example: `console.log ('Line:', [code to get the line])` The result in the console -> `Line: [line number]` so I would know where this `console.log` would have been written on the code.

There is a simple code that returns this number line in js?

Thx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395369/how-to-get-console-log-line-numbers-shown-in-nodejs

Answer (score 1):

You can throw an error (since it contains a stack-trace back to where the error was thrown) and parse it's string representation:

```js
const getLineNumber = () => {
  const getErrorObject = () => {
      try { throw Error('') } catch(err) { return err; }
  }

  const err = getErrorObject();
  const callerLine = err.stack.split("\n").pop();
  return callerLine.slice(callerLine.indexOf("at ")+3, callerLine.length);
}

// The line numbers are wrong inside the inline code snippet runner
// This is because SO adds some wrapper code to each snippet
console.log('Line:', getLineNumber());
console.log('Line:', getLineNumber());
console.log('Line:', getLineNumber());
console.log('Line:', getLineNumber());
```