# Find out which console.log() prints the log

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, logging

I am working on a big project with lots of co-workers and while debugging sometimes finding the code that prints terminal logs gets difficult.

So i am looking for a way (or an extension) to find source of the logs from the terminal.

For example i want to right click on the line of the log from the terminal and click 'go to source' and it will bring the file and focus on the line where that log is printed.
`(I am using VSCode)`

Any one have any tricks for this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: very strange that nobody in the team has noticed the stuff at the right edge of the window

Comment: You should consider using a logging framework, rather than calling `Console.log()`. It would provide additional information, such as timestamps and logging location. I don't do JavaScript development, but I believe that Winston is still the logging framework of choice.

Comment: @rioV8 Lots of logs are printed in the cmd prompt and i want to see only my logs when i am in my branch. I am running mocha tests and i only want mocha to print stuff on the terminal so i want to comment out logs printed by others. I guess i can always comment out every console.log in the project :D

Comment: don't use `console.log` for that purpose, use `log breakpoints`, if that is what you want why ask something different

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395369/how-to-get-console-log-line-numbers-shown-in-nodejs/75109905#75109905

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are *debugging* the project (not just running it in the terminal), you get exactly what you described, in the "Debug Output" tab:

[image: screenshot]

See [this docs page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging) about how to get node.js debugging with VSCode set up.

Comment: Actually the problem here is while the project is in 'development' mode lots of logs are printed in the terminal and i am writing the mocha tests, which run and print results in the terminal and both of them printing in the same terminal results in a really messy and hard to see test result kinda terminal. 
I only want mocha to print stuff on the terminal so i want to comment out logs printed by others in my branch without switching to 'production' mode from 'development' mode. But thanks for showing how `actual` debugging is made, i hope i can detect where those logs are printed from here :)

Comment: This is a problem you need to solve in your testing setup then - there is no way VSCode can determine the source of the log without being connected as debugger - this information simply isn't available if looking only at console output.

Answer (score -1):

I think u can use `console.trace()` which provides a stack trace.