# How to display file, line and position of a piece of code on vscode terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, console, console.log

I have a nodejs project with many controller files, in these files I often use console.log statement to check values. Sometimes my console.log numbers are quite large and they are not necessary so I would like to delete them, but because quite a lot of consoles are printed out on the terminal window, finding the exact location of the console.log command line is quite difficult. tough, is there any way to get the terminal to explicitly show which files and which lines and which locations the console.logs are in.

Please excuse me because I am using google translate to translate the question.

Thank you very much for taking your time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get console.log line numbers shown in Nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395369/how-to-get-console-log-line-numbers-shown-in-nodejs)